# How can I estimate the camera pose with 3d-to-2d-point-correspondences (using opencv)

Tags: java, opencv, computer-vision, camera-calibration, pose-estimation

Hello my goal is to develop *head-tracking functionality to be used in an aircraft (simulator) cockpit*, in order to provide AR to suport civilian pilots to land and fly with bad visual conditions.

My approach is to detect characteristic points (in the dark simulator LEDs) of which I know the 3D coordinates and than compute the estimated (head worn camera's) pose [R|t] (rotation concatinated with translation).

**The problem I do have is that the estimated pose seems to be always wrong and a projection of my 3D points** (which I also used to estimate the pose) **does not overlap with the 2D image points** (or is not visible).

[image: LED detection works but pose estimation and 3D projection not]

My questions are:

**How can I estimate the camera pose with a given set of 2D-to-3D point correspondences.**

**Why does it not work how I try it and where might be sources of error?**

**How accurate must be the measurements (of 3D and 2D points and the camera matrix) to get the theoretical solution working in a real life environment?**

**Will the approach work for coplanar points (x,y axis changed) in theory?**

The hardware I use is the Epson BT-200.

In the aircraft I defined a fixed ordinate to which I expect relative translations and rotations as result of my program. The program detects the image coordinates of (unique) LEDs and matches them to their corresponding 3D coordinate. With a camera matrix I obtained using the open-cv sample android code (https://github.com/Itseez/opencv/tree/master/samples/android/camera-calibration) I try to estimate the pose using solvePnP.

My camera matrix and distortion varries slightly. Here are some values I received from the procedure. I made sure that the circle-distance of my printed out circle pattern is the same as written down in the source-code (measured in Meters).

Here are some examples and how I create the OpenCV Mat of it.

```
//  protected final double[] DISTORTION_MATRIX_VALUES = new double[]{
//          /*This matrix should have 5 values*/
//          0.04569467373955304,
//          0.1402980385369059,
//          0,
//          0,
//          -0.2982135315849994
//  };

//  protected final double[] DISTORTION_MATRIX_VALUES = new double[]{
//          /*This matrix should have 5 values*/
//          0.08245931646421553,
//          -0.9893762277047577,
//          0,
//          0,
//          3.23553287438898
//  };

//  protected final double[] DISTORTION_MATRIX_VALUES = new double[]{
//          /*This matrix should have 5 values*/
//          0.07444480392067945,
//          -0.7817175834131075,
//          0,
//          0,
//          2.65433773093283
//  };
    protected final double[] DISTORTION_MATRIX_VALUES = new double[]{
            /*This matrix should have 5 values*/
            0.08909941096327206,
            -0.9537960457721699,
            0,
            0,
            3.449728790843752
    };

    protected final double[][] CAMERA_MATRIX_VALUES = new double[][]{
            /*This matrix should have 3x3 values*/
//          {748.6595405553738, 0, 319.5},
//          {0, 748.6595405553738, 239.5},
//          {0, 0, 1}
//          {698.1744297982436, 0, 320},
//          {0, 698.1744297982436, 240},
//          {0, 0, 1}
//          {707.1226937511951, 0, 319.5},
//          {0, 707.1226937511951, 239.5},
//          {0, 0, 1}
            {702.1458656346429, 0, 319.5},
            {0, 702.1458656346429, 239.5},
            {0, 0, 1}
    };

    private void initDestortionMatrix(){
        distortionMatrix = new MatOfDouble();
        distortionMatrix.fromArray(DISTORTION_MATRIX_VALUES);
    }

    private void initCameraMatrix(){
        cameraMatrix = new Mat(new Size(3,3), CvType.CV_64F);
        for(int i=0;i<CAMERA_MATRIX_VALUES.length; i++){
            cameraMatrix.put(i, 0, CAMERA_MATRIX_VALUES[i]);
        }
    }
```

To estimate the camera pose I do use solvePnP (and [solvePnPRansac](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#solvepnpransac)) as described in several locations ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16265714/camera-pose-estimation-opencv-pnp),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14444433/calculate-camera-world-position-with-opencv-python),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18637494/camera-position-in-world-coordinate-from-cvsolvepnp#_=_),[4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14515200/python-opencv-solvepnp-yields-wrong-translation-vector?lq=1)). The result of solvePnP I use as input for the Projection ([Calib3d.projectPoints](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#projectpoints)). The inverse of the concatinated result [R|t] I do use as estimated pose.

Because my results in the productive environment were too bad I created a testing environment. In that environment I place the camera (which is because of it's 3D-shape (it's a glass) slightly rotated downwards at a table's edge. This edge I do use as ordinate of the world-coordinate system. I searched how the open-cv coordinate system might be oriented and found different answers (one on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17987465/how-is-orientated-the-camera-coordinate-system-in-opencv) and one in an official youtube-talk about opencv). Anyways I tested if I got the coordinate system right by projection 3D points (described in that coordinate system) on an image and checked if the given world shape stays constant.

So I came up wiht z pointing foreward, y downward and x to the right.
[image: The image shows that the 3D pattern is projected correctly. Only the pose is not esitmated so the points do not overlap]

To get closer to my solution I estimated the pose in my testing environment. The translation vector-output and euler angel output refers to the inverse of [R|t]. The euler angels might not be displayed correct (they might be swaped or wrong, if we take order into account) because I compute it with the convetional (I assume refering to the airplane coordinate system)  equations, using an open-cv coordinate system. (The computation happens in the class Pose which I will attach). But anyways even the translation vector (of the inverse) appeard to be wrong (in my simple test).
[image]

In one test with that Image I had a roll (which might be pitch in airplane coordinates) of 30° and a translation upwards of 50**cm**. That appeard to be more reasonable. So I assumed because my points are coplanar, I might get ambiguous results. So I realized an other test with a point which changed in the Z-Axis. But with this test even the projection failed. [image]

For solvePnP I tried all different solving-algorithm-flags and different parameters for the [ransac algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RANSAC).

Maybe you can somehow help me to find my mistake, or showing me a good path to solve my initial problem. I am going to attach also my debugging source-code with many println statements and the debugging images. **This code contains my point measurements**.

Thanks for your help in advance.

**Class [Main.java](http://www.altergear.net/media/stackover-flow-question-2015-03/Main.java):**
**Class [Pose.java](http://www.altergear.net/media/stackover-flow-question-2015-03/Pose.java):**
**0.png**
[image]

**1.png**
[image]

**EDIT 22.03.2015:**
Finally I have been able to find mistakes I made.

1. I modified a Mat object in a for-loop, because OpenCV works a lot
   with call by reference, and I was not careful enough here. So the
   tvec and rvec for the reprojection were not right.
2. One of my points in the testing environment had (in the image
   coordinates), was tagged wrong due to an axis-direction confusion.

So my approach in general was right. I am not receiving at least (often) valid reprojections in my test-dataset.

Unfortunately the OpenCV PnP algorithms: "ITERATIVE, P3P, EPNP" return various results, and even with using a very unaccurate but close intrinsic guess, the results are only sometimes correct. The [P3P algorithm](http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/~xgao/paper/ieee.pdf) is supposed to provide 3 solutions, but OpenCV only provides one. EPNP is supposed to return good results, but with [EPNP](http://cvlabwww.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/lepetit_ijcv08.pdf) OpenCV returns the worst results, evaluated from my human obersation.

The problem now is, how to filter the inaccurate values or ensure the OpenCV function returns valid ones. (Maybe I shuold modify the native code to receive 3 solutions for PnP).

The [compressed images here](http://www.altergear.net/media/0/result.zip) *(37MB)*, do show my current results (with the ITERATIVE PnP-Solver) , with an intrinsic guess of zero rotation and 75 cm upwards. The print-out has an x-axis foreward, y-axis to the left and z-down, and corrosponding roll, pitch, and yaw angles.

Comment: I found now that the order of my image points, according to the y-coordinate, was wrong. (I had an up-pointnig y-axis in image coordinates). My values become closer but still are not good enough.

Comment: I found now the papers and that EPNP is usable for co-planar points:
P3P: http://www.mmrc.iss.ac.cn/~xgao/paper/ieee.pdf
EPNP: http://cvlabwww.epfl.ch/~lepetit/papers/lepetit_ijcv08.pdf

Comment: I changed the parameter of the square-size in my calibration example from meters to cm but received an almost equal matrix!

Comment: The problem is not yet solved. I created a question here: http://answers.opencv.org/question/58634/what-are-the-requirements-for-solvepnp-and-how-to-improve-my-results/

Answer (score 4):

One thing that i've learned during trying to implement my head tracking system is that you should start from simple problem and than move to more complicated one. Your question is quite ong and unfortunetely i don't have time to analyze it and search for a bug or logical mistake in your code, so at least i will try to give you some hints and working examples.

[Here](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.markdown) is OpenCV tutorial for finding object translation and rotation. It's written in Python, if it is a problem [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/pvathgnrtlhllsy/monitorPosition.cpp?dl=0) part of my old c++ project.
My project performs the same task using solvePnP or solvePnPRansac function (you can change mode). Note that my code it's a part of some old "playground" project, so even after cleaining which i performed it's quite messy. When you run it, show printed chessboard to the camera, press 'p' to start position and rotation estimation, 'm' to change mode (0-ransac, 1-pnp, 2-posit which seems to not work...) or 'd' to turn on/off using dissortion coefficients.
Both projects relies on finding chessboard pattern, but it shoud be easy to modify them to use some other objects.

Camera calibration - while i've been working on my head tracking system i've never managed to calibrate camera twice with the same results... So i decided to use some calibartion file which i've found on github and it worked well - [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398188/opencv-stereosgbm-gives-really-bad-disparity-map/28399661#28399661) you can found a litte more information about that an link to this file.

## ***edit:***

Try to start with as simple as possible solution that gives good results in some (even simple) situation. A good point to start in my opinion is to replace a sheet of paper from your testing environment with printed chessboard from tutorial ([this one](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_pose/py_pose.markdown)) and make it working. Moving from this to your problem will be much easier than beginning with you problem. Try to make any working solution in any programming language - consider using Python or C++ version of OpenCV - there is much more tutorials/examples than to Java version and comparing results from your code with results from some working code will make it much easier. When you will have *some working solution* try to modify it to work with your testing environment. There is a lot of things which may cause it not working right now - not enough points, bug in your code or even in OpenCV Java wrapper, bad interpretation of results, etc...

## ***edit2:***

Using points from your code i've managed to get following results:

> rvec = [[-158.56293283], [   1.46777938], [ -17.32569125]]
> tvec = [[ -36.23910413], [ -82.83704819], [ 266.03157578]]

Unfortunetely, for me it's hard to say whether results are good or not... The only thing that might be *wrong* to me is that 2 angles are different from 0 (or 180). But if you change last row of `points2d` from `(355,37), (353,72), (353,101)` to

> (355,37), (35**5**,72), (35**5**,101)

(i guess it's your mistake, not a correct result) you will get:

> rvec = [[-159.34101842], [   1.04951033], [ -11.43731376]]
> tvec = [[ -25.74308282], [ -82.58461674], [ 268.12321097]]

which might be much closer to the correct result. Changing camera matrix changes results much, so consider testing values from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28398188/opencv-stereosgbm-gives-really-bad-disparity-map/28399661#28399661).

Note that all rvec values are multiplied by `180.0/3.14` - in c++ and python rvec vector returned by solvePnPRansac contains angles in radians.

Comment: I tryed now to do it with the homography but again I receive values which do not make sense. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8927771/computing-camera-pose-with-homography-matrix-based-on-4-coplanar-points

Comment: Thanks a lot for your effort. In my production environment I am very close now. I had a mistake in the part of the re-projection. As mentioned in the comments above, in the testing-environment and the debug code, the y coordinate of 2d-image points, pointed into the wrong direction. 
I see that changing by 2 pixels leads to a result change. Improving accurancy will be the next issue to solve. I am going to post an update of the current status and what helped as soon as possible.

Comment: Do 2 pixels really make such a huge difference? How accurate must the measurements be? I now attached my current status in the question. The circles are the backprojections. Also shown is where my detector estimates the LED and the world and 2d coordinates and the angle and translation guess.